# How to append elements from a list to a new list that dont satisfy a certain condition

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list a=[1,2,3,4,5]
Now iam checking whether any elements add up to give 6

```
for n in a:
    for m in a[1:]:
        x=m+n
        If x==6:
```

Now here is where I need help,if m and n adds up to give 6 I need rest of the elements to be appended to a new list
On first iteration when it reaches 1+5 it gives 6 then I need rest of the elements of a list 2,3,4 to be appended to a new list and display it out as an output

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Since you have not attempted a solution or researched an algorithm, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is this any combination of elements or any two consecutive elements?

Comment: The syntax is wrong. For loop have a small 'f': ```for```. Also, python is case-sensitive. ```X``` and ```x``` are different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question. Since all the elements appear at least once, I made 2 dictionaries: one containing the set of numbers whose sum is 6 and the other containing the rest.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
all_list={} #== Dictionary
all_list2={}
one=1
for n in a: 
    for m in a[1:]: 
        x=m+n 
        if x==6:
            print(m,n)
            all_list2.update({str(one):[m,n]})
            all_list.update({str(one):[l for l in a if l!=n and l!=m]})
            one+=1
            break
print(all_list)
print(all_list2)
```

Comment: hello sir suppose my list contains [1,2,3,4,5] on first iteration when it reaches 1+5 i need an algorithm that append all the elements which was not 1 and 5 that is 2,3,4 to another list say..[2,3,4]

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

a=[1,2,3,4,5]
c=[[(m,a[n]) for n in range(0,len(a)) if n!=a.index(m) and m+a[n]!=6]for m in a]
print(list(itertools.chain(*c)))
```

Check if this works

so if you want only the first element to be checked against all the other elements to sum to 6? if thats the case then i think this would help

```
b=[i for i in a if a.index(i)!=0 and a[0]+i!=6]
print(b)
```

Comment: hello sir suppose my list contains [1,2,3,4,5] on first iteration when it reaches 1+5 i need an algorithm that append all the elements which was not 1 and 5 that is 2,3,4 to another list say..[2,3,4]

Comment: so you want only the first element to be checked against all the other elements to sum to 6? if thats the case then i think this would help

b=[i for i in a if a.index(i)!=0 and a[0]+i!=6]
print(b)

Comment: no not just the first element sir when the iteration gives the result i.e the sum 6 ,all other elements except which gave the sum as 6 should be appended to another list  suppose if the elements where in this order  [7,1,3,4,5]....when the first pair of elements that gives the sum 6 then the rest of the elements should be appended to an another list...the new list would be [7,3,4]